# How to add an item to an ISet<T>?

Tags: c#, collections

I have three classes called `Broker`, `Instrument` and `BrokerInstrument`.

```
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;

public class Broker : ActiveDefaultEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { get; set; }
}

public class Instrument : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get;  set; }
    public virtual string Symbol {get;  set;}
    public virtual ISet<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }        
}

public class BrokerInstrument : Entity
{
    public virtual Broker Broker { get; set; }
    public virtual Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal MinIncrement { get; set; }
}
```

If I create three new objects (one of each type) using those classes how to I associate them? For example:

```
Instrument instrument = new Instrument { 
    Name = "Test Instrument", 
    Symbol = "Test", 
    IsActive = true 
};
Broker broker = new Broker { 
    Name = "My Test Broker", 
    IsActive = true, 
    IsDefault = false 
};
BrokerInstrument brokerInstrument = new BrokerInstrument { 
    Broker = broker, 
    Instrument = instrument, 
    MinIncrement = 0.01M 
};
```

How does the `instrument` "know" that a new `brokerInstrument` is now associated with it? If I now run `if (instrument.Brokerinstruments == null)` I get `true`. Do I have to associate the objects in both the `BrokerInstrument` declaration and then go back and add it to the `instrument.BrokerInstruments ISet`?

If I try and do: `instrument.BrokerInstruments.Add(instrument)` I get an error because its null. Confused. What am I missing? What is the best way to model relationships like this? these objects will get persisted to a database using NHibernate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get an exception because you are not initializing the BrokerInstruments property of the Instrument class (meaning the value of that property is null). To fix that, you need a constructor on Instrument:

```
public Instrument() {
    BrokerInstruments = new HashSet<BrokerInstrument>();
}
```

Now if you want notification of an Instrument being added, that's a different problem.  The easiest and safest way is to make the BrokerInstruments property getter return an IEnumerable, remove the setter, and add a `AddBrokerInstrument` method:

```
// With this, you don't need the constructor above.
private ISet<BrokerInstrument> _brokerInstruments = new HashSet<BrokerInstrument>();

public virtual IEnumerable<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { 
    get { return _brokerInstruments; } 

    // This setter should allow NHibernate to set the property while still hiding it from external callers
    protected set { _brokerInstruments = new HashSet<BrokerInstrument>(value); } 
}

public void AddBrokerInstrument(BrokerInstrument brokerInstrument) { 
     // Any other logic that needs to happen before an instrument is added
     _brokerInstruments.Add(brokerInstrument); 
     // Any other logic that needs to happen after an instrument is added
}
```

I use an IEnumerable above because you want to indicate to the users of this function that they are not allowed to add instruments directly to the set- they need to call your method instead.

Comment: Looks promising however when I run a unit test NHibernate complains with `TestFixture failed: NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException : Could not find a setter for property 'BrokerInstruments' in class 'MooDB.Domain.Instrument'` Do I need to do something special in NHibernate now? It seems quite complicated, but all I want to do is model a one-many relationship in a domain model and then have NHibernate persist changes to the db.

Comment: Ah, I missed the NHibernate bit.  I will modify accordingly...  Done.

Comment: Almost! on the `protected set` line I'm getting error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MooDB.Domain.BrokerInstrument>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet<MooDB.Domain.BrokerInstrument>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Thanks for all your help, seems to work now. I'm still wondering why I have to add the brokerInstrument twice. 1) In my `new BrokerInstrument` declaration, and 2) by using `Instrument.Add()`? You can probably tell I'm new to this. :)

Comment: Because the ISet interface (and none of it's implementors) expose events that notify you when items are added or removed, so you need to control the addition yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6786/discussion-between-mark-allison-and-chris-shain)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to add to a collection you must actually create an instance of it first. This can be done in the respective constructors. My example using `HashSet<t>` as the concrete implementation of `ISet<T>`:

```
public class Broker : ActiveDefaultEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { get; set; }

    public Broker() {
        BrokerInstruments = new HashSet<BrokerInstrument>();
    }
}

public class Instrument : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get;  set; }
    public virtual string Symbol {get;  set;}
    public virtual ISet<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }  

    public Instrument() {
        BrokerInstruments = new HashSet<BrokerInstrument>(); 
    }     
}
```

Then you must add the `brokerInstrument` object to both the `BrokerInstruments`-sets of `Instrument` and `Broker`:

```
var instrument = new Instrument { 
    Name = "Test Instrument", 
    Symbol = "Test", 
    IsActive = true 
};
var broker = new Broker { 
    Name = "My Test Broker", 
    IsActive = true, 
    IsDefault = false 
};
var brokerInstrument = new BrokerInstrument { 
    Broker = broker, 
    Instrument = instrument, 
    MinIncrement = 0.01M 
};
instrument.BrokerInstruments.Add(brokerInstrument);
broker.BrokerInstruments.Add(brokerInstrument);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to do it like this because of namespace clashes and casting error: `BrokerInstruments = (ISet<BrokerInstrument>)new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<BrokerInstrument>();`

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized instrument.BrokerInstruments.
You need: `instrument.BrokerInstruments = new ...;`
I guess new HashSet or new SortedSet